# Loop through a defined number of rows in Dataframe to return string count (win streak)

Tags: python, pandas

Sample of Dataframe below, Looking to create a new column 'Win_Streak' that counts the number of wins over the PREVIOUS 3 (or user defined number) rows. Output I'm looking for shown below

```
      Win_Loss   Win_Streak
0        Win         0
1        Loss        1
2        Loss        2
3        Loss        
4        Win         
5        Win         
6        Loss        
7        Win
8        Loss
9        Win
```

code I've attempted below, output showing 115 in each row- unsure why that is? Maybe I should be using iterrows but not sure how to implement. Appreciate any guidance

```
for i in range(0, len(df), 3):
    df['Win_Streak'] = new_player['Win_Loss'].str.count("Win").sum()
```

Comment: then output should by `01100122` for firs 8 lines?

Comment: As per @Zaraki Kenpachi comment - could you clarify the ```2``` in the 3rd position of your new column?

Comment: each value in win_streak counts the number of "Win" in the previous 3 rows, so for index 2 (3rd position) with Win_Streak count of 2 is counting the number of "Win" in index 3,4,5 so Loss, Win, Win --> 2. Hope this clarifies. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to arrive at a solution by converting Win_Loss column to an integer, 1 == Win, 0 == Loss - then making Win_Streak (3 games prior to current row) column via

```
df['Win_streak'] = df['Win_Loss'].shift(-3).rolling(min_periods=1, window=3).sum()
```